# Rolling point of contact

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

I have been reading "variational principles in classical mechanics" by Douglas Cline and the following page rather confused me. It states that for a cylinder rolling without slipping, the velocity of rolling point of contact is not zero. What am I missing here?
[image: rolling]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Can you convert the picture of the text into typed-out, formatted text? It makes the content index-able by search engines, and shows up better on different devices' displays. For formulae, try [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: I will edit my post as soon as I do that.

Comment: Hint: The point of contact is not a material point fixed relative to the cylinder nor the ground.

Comment: The velocity of the contact point for a rolling motion must be zero, otherwise we have slipping motion

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You have not explained what is confusing about the text which you have quoted.

Comment: whats confusing me is that I thought rolling point of contact velocity is zero for rolling without slipping.

Comment: Two different points are being talked about. The *rolling point of contact* is the point *on the ground* at which contact is made. This moves with the same velocity as the centre of the cylinder. The point of contact which is instantaneously at rest is a fixed point *on the cylinder*. This point moves backwards relative to the centre of the cylinder, with the same velocity, so it is at rest for an instant in the ground frame of referencce.

Answer (score 2):

The contact point is stationary when the wheel (or cylinder) is rolling. Otherwise it wouldn't be rolling, but sliding. The "*without slipping*" part is emphasizing this - if the two surfaces slide over one another, then we have slipping. If they don't, then we have no slipping.

And if they don't slide over one another, well, then they are *stationary* relative to each other.

But only for a moment.

To roll, the wheel therefor isn't sliding over the surface. Rather, the point-of-contact on the wheel is "placed on" the surface and the rest of the wheel moves over this point. Then this point is "lifted off" from the surface. A new point takes over right away, so that there is basically always contact. This contact point is stationary in each moment, but is constantly replaced by a new point on the wheel.